# How to install LDAC codec for Sony WH-XB910N Kubuntu 23.04

Tags: sound, kubuntu, bluetooth, sony

I am trying to install LDAC codec for my Sony WH-XB910N.
I have Kubuntu 23.04 operating system.

Right now, I am using Pipewire:

```
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.78)
```

Here is my Sony WH-XB910N Profile:
[image: Sony Profile]

I do not see LDAC codec option for my headset.

I found these links online but it did not work for me:

1. [How to enable LDAC on Sony WF-1000-MX4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388467/how-to-enable-ldac-on-sony-wf-1000-mx4)
2. https://devicetests.com/enable-ldac-aptx-bluetooth-ubuntu
3. https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-pipewire-on-ubuntu-linux (this is the link I use to install pipewire)